# What is that covering part of the Nerv Logo?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

[image: Nerv Logo]

As you can see, in the logo there is something covering parts of the text. It sort of looks like half of a maple leaf.

What is it and why is it in the Logo?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The glossary contained within The End of Evangelion - Theatrical Program states the leaf to be a [fig leaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fig_leaf).

> The expression "fig leaf" is widely used figuratively to convey the covering up of an act or an object that is embarrassing or distasteful with something of innocuous appearance, **a metaphorical reference to the Biblical Book of Genesis, in which Adam and Eve used fig leaves to cover their nudity after eating the forbidden fruit from the tree of the knowledge of good and evil**.

And as the highlighted text emphasizes, besides hiding or covering something up. It also references to the original sin of eating the forbidden fruit, the fruit of wisdom.